# Calling nc/netcat in python with variable

Tags: python, netcat

I am attempting to call netcat/nc from inside a loop, passing the lcv as the last octet in the command. I am seem to be running into an issue due to the fact that the variable is in the middle of the command. What I would like to do is:

```
for i in 1 to 50
   print i
   nc -nvv 192.168.1.i 21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt
```

So far I have tried:

```
os.system("nc -nvv 192.168.1.",i,"21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt")
```

and

```
subprocess.call(["nv","-nvv 192.168.1.",i,"21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt")
```

Is there an easier way to reference an LVC from within a command executing a system command?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by either "lcv" or "LVC". Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
os.system("nc -nvv 192.168.1.",i,"21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt"
```

… is that `os.system` takes a single string, as a shell command. You're giving it three separate arguments. (Plus, even if this worked as you hoped, it would have to either put a space before the `i` or not put one after the `i`.) You could fix it by any of the usual ways of combining strings:

```
os.system("nc -nvv 192.168.1.{} 21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt".format(i))

os.system("nc -nvv 192.168.1." + str(i) + " 21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt".format(i))
```

---

However, your intuition to try `subprocess.call` instead was a good one. The reason this doesn't work:

```
subprocess.call(["nv","-nvv 192.168.1.",i,"21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt")
```

… is two-fold.

First, you're joining up multiple arguments. This is equivalent to the shell command:

```
nc '-nvv 192.168.1.' '1' '21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt'
```

When what you want is the equivalent to these:

```
nc -nvv 192.168.1.1 21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt
nc '-nvv' '192.168.1.1' '21' '-w' '15' >> 'local_net.txt'
```

You need to split up the arguments properly to get that.

Second, `>> local_net.txt` isn't part of the command itself at all; it's a shell redirection directive. You can't do that without the shell.

If you really want to use the shell, you can do it the same way as with `system`, but putting together a single single:

```
subprocess.call("nc -nvv 192.168.1.{} 21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt".format(i), shell=True)
```

But a better way to do this is to break the arguments up properly, and do the redirection Python-style instead of shell-style:

```
with open('local_net.txt', 'a+b') as f:
    subprocess.call(["nc", "-nvv", "192.168.1.{}".format(i), "21", "-w", "15"],
                    stdout=f)
```

In the file mode, the `a` means to append to the end of the file; the `+` means to update the file if it exists, create it otherwise; the `b` means to open it in binary mode (so you don't translate newlines, if this is Windows—I'm assuming Python 2.x here).

---

Meanwhile, the Python version of `for i in 1 to 50` is `for i in range(1, 51):`. (Note that `51` at the end, because Python ranges are half-open.) So, putting it all together:

```
for i in range(50):
    with open('local_net.txt', 'a+b') as f:
        subprocess.call(["nc", "-nvv", "192.168.1.{}".format(i), "21", "-w", "15"],
                        stdout=f)
```

---

It's worth noting that you can do this in most sh-like shells, including bash, without needing Python at all. And for something this simple, it may be easier:

```
for i in {1..50}; do
    nc -nvv 192.168.1.${i} 21 -w 15 >> local_net.txt
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much, not only do you have multiple solutions. You'ev explained what I was doing wrong. Thank you!